# Aws configure is not saving configuration data in credentials and config files on windows 10

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to configure `AWS CONFIGURE` via `AWS CLI` on my laptop having Windows 10 professional. This is not the first time I am configuring AWS CONFIGURE. I already have many profiles settings.
I have enough free system memory and storage and have sufficient rights to run aws configure. I am using Python 3.6

Here is the detail, how I am trying to setup AWS CONFIGURE.
[image]

When I run this command again, it asks all the values again.
[image]

Even if I run an AWS CLI command using this new profile; to create a lambda function ( `aws lambda create-function xxxxxxxxx --profile lambdaprofile` ).

It gives below error.

```
The config profile (lambdaprofile) could not be found.
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Some times this issue happens and AWS CLI is unable to set new profile and settings in config file.
Here is a fix of this issue.
Run below command from windows console.

```
notepad %USERPROFILE%\.aws\credentials
```

You will see last line of credentials file with overlapping line.
e.g in your particular case, it would be showing like below.

```
region = us-east-1[lambdaprofile]
aws_access_key_id = AKIAIGCOZJBAKIAIGCOZJB
aws_secret_access_key = gHZWwhUxRLtwQRUknGgHZWwhUxRLtwQRUknG
region = use-east-1
```

Similar issue would be in config file, which can be checked by opening this file.

```
notepad %USERPROFILE%\.aws\config
```

To fix this issue set [lambdaprofile] to new line, preferably add another empty line before [lambdaprofile]. It should look like below.

```
region = us-east-1

[lambdaprofile]
aws_access_key_id = AKIAIGCOZJBAKIAIGCOZJB
aws_secret_access_key = gHZWwhUxRLtwQRUknGgHZWwhUxRLtwQRUknG
region = use-east-1
```

Also do the same fix in config file. After fixing it, if you will run aws configure --profile lambdaprofile it should show the previously saved values in credentials and config files.
You may also check if values are saved or not with below command.

```
aws configure list --profile lambdaprofile
```

Alternately to the fix detail mentioned above, you can also set new profile directly with `AWS CONFIGURE SET`
e.g in your particular case.

```
aws configure --profile lambdaprofile set aws_access_key_id AKIAIGCOZJBAKIAIGCOZJB
aws configure --profile lambdaprofile set aws_secret_access_key gHZWwhUxRLtwQRUknGgHZWwhUxRLtwQRUknG
aws configure --profile lambdaprofile set region use-east-1
```

or

```
aws configure set profile.lambdaprofile.aws_access_key_id AKIAIGCOZJBAKIAIGCOZJB
aws configure set profile.lambdaprofile.aws_secret_access_key gHZWwhUxRLtwQRUknGgHZWwhUxRLtwQRUknG
aws configure set profile.lambdaprofile.region use-east-1
```

Comment: Thank you. Being able to programmatically create new profiles and assign configs to them is very convenient. `aws configure set profile.temp.aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_app1` etc, and then `aws --profile temp --endpoint-url=https:my-endpoint.com s3 ls my-bucket`